# why can't I add chars to a new string?

Tags: java, string, char

code:

```
String st = "abc";
String sl = st.charAt(0)+st.charAt(st.length()-1));
```

The second line is wrong for some reason and I don't know why

Comment: What language is the program?

Comment: its Java ......

Comment: *wrong for some reason and I don't know why* - without you elaborating on what is wrong... neither does anyone, do you have an error, unexpected results...?

Comment: I dont know why, I just wrote these two lines (copied from some book which means it supposed to be fine) and the eclipse says it's wrong.. but thank you

Comment: Please provide the actual error eclipse is giving you. Remember we have a lot less context than you do on this issue. Consider checking out [ask] for some tips.

Comment: The sum of two chars is a number, it is not an string.

Comment: well this is what it says:  "- Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to 
  String"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The book is wrong, and Eclipse is right.

In Java, you can write `"abc" + whatever`, or `whatever + "abc"`, and it concatenates the strings -- because one side is a `String`.

But in `st.charAt(0)+st.charAt(st.length()-1))`, neither side is a `String`.  They're both `char`s.  So Java won't give you a `String` back.

Instead, Java will actually technically give you an `int`.  Here are the gritty details from the Java Language Specification, which describes exactly how Java works:

1. [JLS 4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2) specifies that `char` is considered a *numeric type.*
2. [JLS 15.18.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2) specifies what `+` does to values of numeric types.
3. In particular, it specifies that the first thing done to them is binary numeric promotion, which converts both `char`s to `int` by [JLS 5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2).  Then it adds them, and the result is still an `int`.

To get what you *want* to happen, probably the simplest solution is to write

```
String sl = st.charAt(0) + "" + st.charAt(st.length() - 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because charAt returns char [ int ]

use this code :

```
String st = "abc";
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
str.append(st.charAt(0));
str.append(st.charAt(st.length() - 1));
System.out.println(str.toString());
```

append method accept the char, or string, ..

Answer (score 0):

> well this is what it says: "- Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to String"

Meaning exactly what @Jaime said. If I remember correctly, a char is technically represented by an integer value. (i.e. 'a' + 1 = 'b'). So you're adding two char values, which isn't the same thing as adding two strings together, or even concatenating two char values. One fix would be to use `String.valueOf(st.charAt(0)) + String.valueOf(st.charAt(st.length()-1)))` to concatenate the two char values.